# Is it possible to use teamviewer's VPN on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, teamviewer

Is it possible to use Teamvewer's VPN on Ubuntu?

If so, how it could be done, I wonder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the VPN functionality is not currently supported on Linux.
They may have plans for it in the future, however.

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

Download their Linux client from the web site (it runs with WINE) and Setup Unattended Access...

Comment: it's already installed. And as I understand "Unattended Access" is switched on, because I can connect to my Ubuntu machine from other machines. But items of "Extrax -> VPN ->" menu are disabled (I can't "start", "stop", "status..."). Am I correct at my understanding of switched on "Unattended Access", or I should perform some special actions to really switch it on?

Comment: Linux VPN is not possible. I just talked to Mr. Böhme of Teamviewer about that.